# PHP Array: array filter with argument

Tags: php, arrays

I have this simple array in PHP that I need to filter based on an array of tags matching those in the array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Introduction
            [id] => 798162f0-d779-46b6-96cb-ede246bf4f3f
            [tags] => Array
                (
                    [0] => client corp
                    [1] => version 2
                )
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Chapter one
            [id] => 761e1909-34b3-4733-aab6-ebef26d3fcb9
            [tags] => Array
                (
                    [0] => pro feature
                )
        )
)
```

When supplied with 'client corp', the output should be the above array with only the first item.

So far I have this:

```
$selectedTree = array_filter($tree,"checkForTags");

function checkForTags($var){

   $arr = $var->tags;
   $test = in_array("client corp", $arr, true);

   return ($test);
}
```

However, the result is that it's not filtering. When I `echo $test`, I get `1` all the time. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try using the `array_map()` function instead of the `array_filter()` function: http://php.net/array_map

Comment: Are you sure $arr does not always contains "client corp"?

Comment: to me your code works  http://codepad.org/AvpbTE9W

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
$selectedTree = array_filter(array_map("checkForTags", $tree ,array_fill(0, count($tree), 'client corp')));

function checkForTags($var, $exclude){
   $arr = $var->tags;
   $test = in_array($exclude, $arr, true);
   return ($test ? $var : false);
}
```

`array_map()` makes sure you can pass arguments to the array. It returns each value altered. So in the returning array, some values are present, others are set to false. `array_filter()` with no callback filters all falsey values from that array and you are left with the desired result

Comment: Sorry... small typo there... Updated the answer

Comment: why is there both an `array_filter` and an `array_map`?

Comment: @greener `array_map()` makes sure you can pass arguments to the array. It returns each value altered. So in the returning array, some values are present, others are set to false. `array_filter()` with no callback filters all falsey values from that array and you are left with the desired result

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. When I replace the array values with the json payload `array(Input::json("selectedTags"))` it filters out everything again. Something small is missing but your answer is correct.

Comment: Upon further testing, it looks like there are issues with this approach. If I pass `pro feature` as the argument, the returned array is empty when it should instead show the second item of the initial array.

Comment: @greener I saw that now... was a small bug in the code which I fixed the second array passed to `array_map()` should be of an equal size of the first. I fixed this by using `array_fill()`. I have updated the answer with the bugfix. See this for the complete code: http://codepad.org/dPIpq96u

Answer (score 0):

The `in_array()` function returns TRUE if needle is found in the array and FALSE otherwise. So by getting 1 as a result that means that "client corp" is found.

Check [PHP in_array() manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

You can user `array_search()` to return the array key instead of using `in_array()`.